# Where does R store subset information in glm object?

Tags: r, glm

I'm trying to do some post-processing of a large number of glm models that I am working with, but I need to extract information about the data subset from the glm objects.

As a toy example:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100,x,0.5)
s<-sample(c(T,F),100,replace=T)
myGlm <- glm(y~x, subset= s)
```

From this, I need to know which of the 100 observations were used by getting the information out of `myGlm`. I thought that `myGlm$data` would have the subsetted data, but it actually has all 100 observations in it. I looked through `str(myGlm)` to no avail. However, it is quite clear that somewhere in the object, information about the subset `s` is stored.

This seems like it should be totally trivial!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.numeric(rownames(myGlm$model))
```

Comment: `rownames(model.frame(myGlm))` might be slightly preferable, since it uses an accessor method rather than digging into the model structure itself (not that the internal structure of `glm` objects is likely to change much at this point)